# Correct structure for json unmarshal

Tags: arrays, json, object, go

I can't figure out how to build a structure for this json object in golang:

```
{
    "response": [1702487, {
            "uid": 150261846,
            "first_name": "Олег",
            "last_name": "Брейн"
        }, {
            "uid": 53260546,
            "first_name": "Олег",
            "last_name": "Лобацевич"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see there is no keys names for array and for count too.

Would be glad if you can help

Comment: from where are you expecting this response? what is `1702487`?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you'll have to punt and use interface{} somewhere, for example:

```
    package main

    import (
            "fmt"
            "encoding/json"
    )

    type JsObject struct {
            Response []interface{}
    }

    func main() {
            bs := []byte(`{"response":[1702487,{"uid":150261846,"first_name":"Олег","last_name":"Брейн"},{"uid":53260546,"first_name":"Олег","last_name":"Лобацевич"}]}`)
            var jso JsObject
            json.Unmarshal(bs, &jso)
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", jso)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Json to go is quite handy for this sort of thing:

https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

If you can remove the spurious 1702487 which makes this a heterogenous list, you should be able to parse it easily into a proper structure, otherwise you might be stuck using interface:

https://play.golang.org/p/w7ebLTuOj9

Presumably you want an array of structs like this:

```
type Person struct {
  UID       int `json:"uid"`
  FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
  LastName  string `json:"last_name"`
}
```

not sure what 1702487 is but if uid of request, it doesn't really belong in the array.

Comment: 1702487 is the total count of people whose first name is the same as you in that object

Comment: Your structure is perfectly fine, but the response still have the key named "response", so the structure is gonna look different. Is there any way to remove or skip keys? Like jump right into the person object, ignoring "response" and that count number

Comment: I would clean the data of the int key in the array (you can leave the resonse key) then use this. The alternative is to parse manually with map[string]interface{} as far as I can see. If you control data I'd change it to make parsing not you're stuck cleaning it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Response []interface{} `json:"response"`
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this fixes the problem.